# Copying the corresponding values from a column to another

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

Let's suppose we have 3 columns: A, B and C

```
|  A  |   B   |  C      |

|Stan |   1   |Producer |       

|Mike |   2   |Singer   |

|Jim  |   3   |Actor    |

|Stan |   4   |         |
```

I wanna fill the rest of the C column, where I can check what is the value corresponding to Stan (Which is Musician) and write it in C colum

Comment: Where are the values (like musician) you want to look up? Sounds like a simple VLOOKUP will do: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us

Comment: Do you ask us "where I can check what is the value corresponding to Stan"? Do you have it somewhere in the same sheet, workbook, different workbook? In fact, what do you want to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

Create the table with the columns, select the whole range (including headers), go to Design tab, Format as table and create a table. In case you need to add some other details in the table just write the values to the next available line and there is no need to change anything in the formulas.

Then use the below formula in `B1:B4`:

`=IFNA(VLOOKUP(A1,Table1,3,FALSE),"No output")`

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

in C5:

```
=VLOOKUP(A5,A$1:C4,3,0)
```

Vlookup picks the first match, only. You would need lookupall if you want every match. But I think with your data and table, vlookup is sufficient.

So, if your table was 10000's rows deep, you would still be able to fill all your missing C's with `=VLOOKUP(A5,A$2:C$1000,3,0)` or `=VLOOKUP(A5,A$2:C1000,3,0)` and apply that formula to every empty Cell in C and you would be able to full every empty cell in C provided the data existed in range `A$1:A$1000` or `A$1:A**Whteverrownumberyouron**`

For any number row, Provided your lookup values all reside above the row your working ( in your case),

```
=VLOOKUP(A5,A$1:C**numberoftherowyouron**,3,0)
```

and scroll down on a filtered range to fill all the missing C's up.

Sometimes my actual data lies below the row im trying to fill, so naturally adjust the lookup range accordingly.

see how the searched range will gradually increase if you fix the first cell but allow the last cell to change, as in `A$1:A**ROWNUMBER**` as opposed to A$1:A$1000 (which is a fixed range). So its upto you how you wish to implement it.

Sometimes, it might just simpler and cleaner, as [Error 1004's answer below,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62532411/copying-the-corresponding-values-from-a-column-to-another/62532713#62532713) to copy all deffinately known values to another sheet or table (this become your ID's), and you just lookup that specific table & columns to fill your C's.

note, without a seperate lookup table, like in Error 1004's below, if Stan's first C Value was empty, in your example, you would get 0. Bare that in mind.